# Force linker to export a resolved symbol when creating shared library

Tags: linker, shared-libraries, ld

I am creating a shared library using c++ -shared (which is gcc running on x86_64). I can't manage to strip my problem down to a minimal test case, but the issue I'm having is that I am creating a .so out of a bunch of .o files. One of those .o files exports a symbol (nm shows 'D') that I want exported from the .so. Others of the .o's require that symbol (nm shows 'U'). As a result, the linker makes that symbol local in the resulting .so (nm shows 'd').

If I eliminate the requiring .o's from the command line, the .so **does** export the symbol. So it seems like the linker is deciding that since other .o's used to build the .so require the symbol, that it must *only* be needed by those .o's and it needn't be exported for real.

When I try to construct a minimal test case, it doesn't work this way; the symbol is always exported whether or not I add in a .o that requires it.

My full command line is:

`c++  -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Woverloaded-virtual -Wsynth -Wno-ctor-dtor-privacy -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wcast-align -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-variadic-macros -pedantic -Wno-long-long -gdwarf-2 -fno-strict-aliasing -pthread -pipe  -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG -DDEBUG_sfink -DTRACING -gdwarf-2 -fPIC -shared -Wl,-z,defs -Wl,-h,libmozjs.so -o libmozjs.so  jsapi.o jsarena.o jsarray.o jsatom.o jsbool.o jscntxt.o jsdate.o jsdbgapi.o jsdhash.o jsdtoa.o jsemit.o jsexn.o jsfun.o jsgc.o jsgcchunk.o jshash.o jsinterp.o jsinvoke.o jsiter.o jslock.o jslog2.o jsmath.o jsnativestack.o jsnum.o jsobj.o json.o jsopcode.o jsparse.o jsproxy.o jsprf.o jspropertycache.o jspropertytree.o jsregexp.o jsscan.o jsscope.o jsscript.o jsstr.o jstask.o jstypedarray.o jsutil.o jswrapper.o jsxdrapi.o jsxml.o prmjtime.o jsdtracef.o jstracer.o Assembler.o Allocator.o CodeAlloc.o Containers.o Fragmento.o LIR.o njconfig.o RegAlloc.o avmplus.o NativeX64.o jsbuiltins.o VMPI.o CTypes.o Library.o mozjs-dtrace.o    -lpthread    -Wl,-rpath-link,/bin -Wl,-rpath-link,/lib -Wl,--whole-archive ctypes/libffi/.libs/libffi.a  -Wl,--no-whole-archive -L/home/sfink/moz-central/obj-dtrace/dist/lib -lplds4 -lplc4 -lnspr4 -lpthread -ldl -ldl -lm  -lm -ldl`

I get the same behavior with the core command that this invokes (I also manually pruned out some irrelevant flags):

`/usr/bin/ld --no-add-needed --eh-frame-hdr --build-id -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu -shared -o libmozjs.so /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/../../../../lib64/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/../../.. jsapi.o jsarena.o jsarray.o jsatom.o jsbool.o jscntxt.o jsdate.o jsdbgapi.o jsdhash.o jsdtoa.o jsemit.o jsexn.o jsfun.o jsgc.o jsgcchunk.o jshash.o jsinterp.o jsinvoke.o jsiter.o jslock.o jslog2.o jsmath.o jsnativestack.o jsnum.o jsobj.o json.o jsopcode.o jsparse.o jsproxy.o jsprf.o jspropertycache.o jspropertytree.o jsregexp.o jsscan.o jsscope.o jsscript.o jsstr.o jstask.o jstypedarray.o jsutil.o jswrapper.o jsxdrapi.o jsxml.o prmjtime.o jsdtracef.o jstracer.o Assembler.o Allocator.o CodeAlloc.o Containers.o Fragmento.o LIR.o njconfig.o RegAlloc.o avmplus.o NativeX64.o jsbuiltins.o VMPI.o mozjs-dtrace.o -lnspr4 -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lpthread -lc -lgcc_s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/../../../../lib64/crtn.o`

**Update**: probably more importantly, those symbols are in a different section, and have hidden visibility. Using objcopy to make them global doesn't help. I don't know what the rules are for which sections to use for what.

Comment: It sounds like you may be hitting some bug in ld.  Can you try the latest version of ld (2.20.1)?

Comment: ld --version says: GNU ld version 2.20.51.0.2-20.fc13 20091009. I'll try virgin 2.20.1 to see if it matters. Perhaps it's a Fedora patch that broke this. I take it that this is not expected behavior? Linkerz is hard.

Comment: Nope, same behavior with standard 2.20.1.